# Phonegap: Cannot call remote hosts via HTTP

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ajax, cordova

I created a HTML5 website with jQuery and jQueryMobile.

If I run it in the browser, everything works fine.

When I deploy it to the iPhone Simulator via Phonegap, it won't find the jQuery object ($) which I included like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

console.log($); // undefined
```

If I modify the src attribute, so that my app uses a local copy of jQuery, the jQuery objects exists:

```
<script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>

console.log($); // works
```

**BUT** then I noticed that **none of my Ajax calls within my app work**.

So, I assume that my iPhone app refuses HTTP connections to remote hosts.

How can I fix this?

---

**Update:** I checked the URL where my app is deployed within the iPhone app and it looks like this:

file:///Users/mobile/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/9767E436-B93422-5423-5HLD-1680170C8AC5/MyApp.app/www/index.html

Comment: Are you running your web application on HTTPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify which hosts you allow to connect to in the Cordova.plist

This feature is called [Whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) and avoids your app to connect to servers you don't want to

Comment: Yep, that did the trick! I opened Cordova.plist in Xode and added the value `*.jquery.com` to `ExternalHosts`. That worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about if we check the page on a browser.